# Incorrect ViewController Orientation After Segue IOS7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, segue, landscape

I have 2 `ViewControllers`, the main one with `shouldAutoRotate-NO` and the second one with `shouldAutoRotate-YES`.
I'm presenting the second `ViewController` with the function `presentViewController:` and using `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` because I have a transparent Background on the second one to still view the first one on the back.

The problem is that when I am in the first `ViewController` in "Landscape" (appearing in Portrait because of the `shouldAutoRote-NO`) and I present the second `ViewController`, the second one appears right in landscape, but if I rotate my iPhone back to portrait I will not rotate, unless I rotate my phone back to landscape what makes the orientations start working again as normal.

The behaviour of the Status Bar is always the correct one, the problem is with the `ViewControllers`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Your can simply provide what type of orientation you want in present view controller.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is no longer supported since ios5, plus this doesn't really addresses the problem described in the post, thanks!!